# Twitter: "Fetching the page failed because other errors", on Forge NGINX server with SSL

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx, twitter

Our website is running on Laravel Forge with 'Let's encrypt SSL,' and HTTPS is OK in the browser.
We added FB, Twitter meta tags for having branded FB and Twitter cards when sharing on these media.

Following 'ERROR: Fetching the page failed because of other errors. ' is raised when trying to display Twitter card in tweets (tested with https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) and this is linked, after research, to this dedicated well-known issue:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/error-fetching-the-page-failed-because-ssl-handshake-error/30204/9.

It establishes that on Apache server serving different sites, a ServerName directive that matches the SSL certificate’s CN is needed to avoid Apache sending the local hostname or the IP of the connection.

How to solve this Twitter issue on Forge NGINX server? Does someone know if this is the similar issue as Apache server and what configuration changes are needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've lost the better half of a day on this issue, likely digging through the same threads as you.  This thread held the answer: https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-card-error-fetching-the-page-failed-because-other-errors/112895/6

Enabling AES128 as an ssl cipher will allow the Twitterbot to connect.  This can be done within the nginx configuration within the Forge UI.

Happy tweeting!

Comment: I have an AES256 as ssl cipher with lets encrypty on NGIX. I hesitate to change all the configuration to test if AES128 can be the solution. Can you confirm if it worked for you?All issues solved with Twitter bot? I am having a Laravel website with Forge

Comment: Yes, I've had no issues with twitter cards since making this change (you can check @whiskr for example).

Comment: Thks...all working as per link provided above.Happy coding to you

Comment: Just to add to this, if your certificate is missing the complete SSL chain it can cause this issue as well despite most browsers not complaining

Comment: "I've lost the better half of a day on this issue, likely digging through the same threads as you. ": yay stack overflow <3